# Number of bit string with 3 consecutive zero or 3 consecutive one

Tags: combinatorics

What is the number of 10-bit binary strings where the string contains 3 consecutive $0$s or 3 consecutive $1$s?

I got the answer $2^7+7\cdot 2^6$ but it does not match the answer. What was my mistake?

**EDIT:**
I use this concept : In 10 bit out string there will be 8 position where we can start 3 consecutive 0s (1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8) when we place string 123 we have 2^7 ways 000xxxxxxx. when we start 2nd position it will we 1000xxxxxxx. in 3rd position it x1000xxxxx,4th xx1000xxxx and so on . In that's way I get 2^7 +7.2^6 (I found this approach in similar post)

Comment: If you do not tell us *how* you got that answer, we're not going to be able to see your mistake.

Answer (score 3):

Instead, let's count the number of binary strings of length $10$ that *do not* contain three $1$s in a row or three $0$s in a row.
Such a string must be composed of 1 or 2 $0$s, followed by 1 or 2 $1$s, followed by 1 or 2 $0$s, followed by 1 or 2 $1$s, and so on (or it can start with $0$s instead of $1$s).

Let $a$ be the number of single $0$s or $1$s, and $b$ be the number of doubles, i.e. $00$s or $11$s. Then $a + 2b = 10$.
Additionally,  the number of strings of this form is $2 \binom{a+b}{b}$. Why? The $2$ is for starting with $0$s or starting with $1$s, and then the $\binom{a+b}{b}$ splits the strings into $a+b$ blocks where each block is either one or two of the same character and then selects $b$ of those $a+b$ blocks to be two of the same character.

Setting $a = 10 - 2b$,
we therefore have that the number of strings with no $111$s or $000$s is
$$
\sum_{b \ge 0} 2\binom{10 - b}{b}
$$
This is
$$
2 \left[ \binom{10}{0} + \binom{9}{1} + \binom{8}{2} +
\binom{7}{3} + \binom{6}{4} + \binom{5}{5} \right]
= 2 F_{11}
$$
where $F_{11}$ is the $11$th Fibonacci number.
Now $F_{11} = 89$.

To get your final answer, make sure to subtract this from the total number of strings.

---

P.S. Unfortunately, I do not understand where your answer
$$
2^7+7\cdot 2^6
$$
came from. If you specify your reasoning, then we can point out the mistake.

Comment: I use this concept : In10 bit out string there will be 8 position where we can start 3 consecutive 0s (1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8) when we place string 123 we have 2^7 ways 000xxxxxxx. when we start 2nd position it will we 1000xxxxxxx. in 3rd position it x1000xxxxx,4th xx1000xxxx and so on . In that's way I get 2^7 +7.2^6 {I found this approach in similar post}

Comment: @RinkyParmar That is wrong because you have counted strings like 0001000xxx twice.

Comment: @RinkyParmar Additionally, what about 3 consecutive 1s? You haven't counted that. And you need to then deal with if there are 3 consecutive 0s AND 3 consecutive 1s, like x000x111xx.

Comment: @EricAuld thx fixed

Answer (score 0):

Here's a (lengthy) hint.

If you count the strings directly I'd think there'd be a lot of cases to consider.  (I read the question as counting the number of bit strings with *at least* three consecutive zeroes *or at least* three consecutive ones.)  You could have both $000$ and $111$ in the string, a string of five $1$s, etc., and have to sort all of them out as to count them all only once.

In this case, it may be easier to count the number of strings that contain *no more than* two consecutive zeroes, *and no more than* two consecutive ones.  These cases are easier to divide up.

Then, whatever's left from the $1024$ possible strings is your answer.

The structure of these strings is alternating groups of no more than two $0$s and two $1$s.  You can have zero to five groups of two in the string.

You can simplify the counting even more by considering those numbers that start with $1$, and then doubling what you find.

For no groups of two numbers, there is $1010101010$ and (flipping the bits) $0101010101$.

For five groups of two numbers, there is $1100110011$ and $0011001100$.

For *one* group of two numbers, the group of two can be in one of nine "slots" in the number, so there are $9\cdot2 = 18$ such numbers.

Can you take it from here?